# How can I calculate the travel time in warp?

Tags: eve-online

There are situations where it is very useful to know roughly how much time it will take to travel in warp between two points. If you have a bait ship somewhere, it is good to know how long it'll have to survive until the main fleet arrives. Or if you're in smaller ships and want to use the difference in warp speed to split an enemy gang, knowing the exact time it takes for any ship to warp a specific distance is very useful.

The maximum warp speed is easy, but in most situations the acceleration and decelaration in warp as well as the align time are the more important factors. What I'd like to know is a rough formula that would enable me to quickly estimate the time it'll take a specific ship to warp a specific distance.

Comment: Probably need some parameters set to eliminate deviation, such as align time, starting velocity, etc.

Comment: To take out the align part of the equation I found this as a possible example of how long it takes to first get into warp:

V(t) = Vmax*(1-e^-(t / (A*M)))

V(t) = Velocity after time t (in seconds)
Vmax = Max Velocity
t = Time in seconds
A = Inertia Modifier
M = Total mass / 1.000.000 (if a ship weights 120.000.000 kg M would be equal to 120).

If you want to find out your time to warp from a standstill you can simplify the formula to:
Time to warp = 1.386 * Inertia Modifier * Mass / 1.000.000

1.386 in that comes from -ln(1-(target speed / top speed)).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [someone](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1514884) has done some research on the subject already.